# Guided Access Mode preventing iOS updates from MDM console?

Tags: ios, software-update, mobile-device-management

Our organization uses an enterprise MDM product that features remote updating. All conditions specified by the MDM vendor are being met for this to work, but it doesn't. I discovered that as soon as a kiosk is "Ended" from guided access mode, the pending download of iOS begins. Since all fleets of kiosks are locked down in some way, updating should work in this mode, or there would be no purpose to the existence of remote updating. Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: As far as I understand, you need to check with the MDM provider to see if the desired is supported or if anything is preventing it from their end.

Comment: @NimeshNeema - I can edit to make it more clear, but I already alluded to this when I said "all conditions are being met".